# Python Selenium Web Automation How Do You Click A Login Button

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate the downloads of specific files for my organization. 
In doing so I came across Browser Automation with Selenium. 
I got to the point where I can inject user credentials, but now I need to login to the page by clicking on the login button.

Here is the parent URL, in which I inject my credentials
https://www.accuplacer.org

Then I need to click on the login button.
Here is the inspect output of that element:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary pull-left " ng-disabled="loginDisable &amp;&amp; isFullyLoaded">
                                    <!-- ngIf: loginSpin && !traceIE -->
                                    <!-- ngIf: loginSpin && traceIE -->
                                    Login
                                 </button>
```

Here is the code I have so far, I know it's basic, and I am working on cleaning it up and defining somethings into functions.

```
import selenium
import os
import unittest
import requests
import time
from selenium import webdriver

#URL Variables
login_url = 'https://www.accuplacer.org/'
redirect_url = 'https://www.accuplacer.org/api/home.html#/'
reports_scheduler_url = 'https://www.accuplacer.org/api/home.html#/reportScheduler'
custom_reports_url = 'https://www.accuplacer.org/api/home.html#/customReports'

#WebDriver Path
browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\chromedriver.exe")

browser.get("https://www.accuplacer.org")

username = browser.find_element_by_id("login")
password = browser.find_element_by_id("password")
#submit = browser.find_element_by_id("Login")
username.send_keys("uname")
password.send_keys("test")

#browser.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
#browser.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

#submit.click()
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('btn btn-log btn-primary pull-left').click()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `CSS` locator is wrong. Try with below `css` locator with explicit wait.

```
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".btn.btn-lg.btn-primary.pull-left")))
element.click();
```

For this piece of code you need below import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Yeah, I just discovered that as well. I should have been using: ```browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.btn.btn-lg.btn-primary').click()

```

Comment: I was able to do it without the additional imports, but I may end up doing that to work in some functionality with the login button.

Comment: Explicit wait is standard practice to use so i have mentioned it too in answer

Comment: Any reason to leave out the `<button>` tag?

Comment: No specific reason. “TagName.ClassName” or “.className” both are correct CSS expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the above, but I did not define the element in the way that Muzzamil did. 
Instead I just used the following for #submit.click

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.btn.btn-lg.btn-primary').click()
```